# Glitchy audio output, no underruns

Tags: c, linux, audio, qemu, alsa

When using snd_pcm_writei() in non-blocking mode everything works perfect for a while but eventually the audio gets choppy. It sounds like the ring buffer pointers are getting out of sync (ie. sometimes I can tell that the audio is playing out of order). How long it takes for the problem to start it's hardware dependent. On a Gentoo box on real hardware it seldom happens, but on a buildroot system running on QEMU it happens after about 5 minutes. On both cases draining the pcm stream fixes the problem. I have verified that I'm writing the samples correctly by also writting them to a file and playing them with aplay.

Currently I'm setting avail_min to the period size (1024 frames) and calling snd_pcm_wait() before writting chunks of the period size. But I tried a number of different variations (different chunk sizes, checking avail myself and use pthread_cond_timedwait() instead of snd_pcm_wait(), etc). But the only thing that works fine is using blocking mode but I can not do that.

You can see the current source code here: https://bitbucket.org/frodzdev/mediabox/src/5a6471316c7ae481b329e7e0d4af1bb68a32e71d/src/audio.c?at=staging&fileviewer=file-view-default (it needs a little cleanup since I'm trying all kinds of things). The code that does the actual IO starts at line 375.

Edit:
I think I got a solution but I don't understand why it seems to work. It seems that it does not matter if I'm using non-blocking mode, the problem is when I wait to make sure there's room on the buffer (either through snd_pcm_wait(), pthread_cond_timedwait(), or usleep()).

The version that seems to work is here: https://bitbucket.org/frodzdev/mediabox/src/c3eb290087d9bbe0d5f37653a33a1ba88ef0628b/src/audio.c?fileviewer=file-view-default. I switched to blocking mode while still waiting before calling snd_pcm_writei() and it didn't made a difference. Then I added the call to snd_pcm_avail() before calling snd_pcm_status() on avbox_audiostream_gettime(). This function is called constantly by another thread to get the stream clock and it only uses snd_pcm_status() to get the timestamps. Now it seems to work (at least it is a lot less probable to happen) but I don't understand exactly why. I understand that snd_pcm_avail() will synchronize the pointers with the kernel but I don't really understand when it needs to be called and the difference between snd_pcm_state() et al and snd_pcm_status(). Does snd_pcm_status() also synchronize anything? It seems not because sometimes snd_pcm_status_get_state() will return RUNNING when snd_pcm_avail() returns -EPIPE. The ALSA documentation is really vague. Perhaps understanding these things will help me understand my problem?

Now, when I said that it seems to be working I mean that I cannot reproduce it on real hardware. It still happens on QEMU though way less often. But considering that on the next commit I switched to blocking mode without waiting (which I've used in the past and never had a problem with on real hardware) and it still happens in QEMU and also the fact that this is a common issue with QEMU I'm starting to think that I may have fixed the issue on my end and now it's just a QEMU problem. Is there any way to determine if the problem is a bug on my end that is easier to trigger on the emulator or if it's just an emulator problem?

Edit: I realize that I should fill the buffer before waiting but at this point my concern is not to prevent underruns but to make sure that my code can handle them when they happen. Besides the buffer is filling up after a few iterations. I confirmed this by outputing avail, buffer_size, etc before writing each packet and the numbers I get don't make perfect sense, they show an error of 1 or 2 periods about every 8th period. Also (and this is the main problem) I'm not detecting any underruns, the audio get choppy but all writes succeed. In fact, if the problem start happening and I trigger an underrun by overloading the CPU it will correct itself when the pcm is reset.

Answer (score 1):

In [line 505](https://bitbucket.org/frodzdev/mediabox/src/5a6471316c7ae481b329e7e0d4af1bb68a32e71d/src/audio.c?at=staging&fileviewer=file-view-default#audio.c-505): You're using time as argument to malloc.

In [line 568](https://bitbucket.org/frodzdev/mediabox/src/5a6471316c7ae481b329e7e0d4af1bb68a32e71d/src/audio.c?at=staging&fileviewer=file-view-default#audio.c-568): Weren't you playing audio? In this case you should do wait only after you wrote the frames. Let's think ...

Audio device generates an interrupt when it terminates to process a period.

```
|  period A  |  period B  |
             ^            ^
            irq          irq
```

Before you start the pcm, audio device doesn't generate any interrupt. Notice [here](https://bitbucket.org/frodzdev/mediabox/src/5a6471316c7ae481b329e7e0d4af1bb68a32e71d/src/audio.c?at=staging&fileviewer=file-view-default#audio.c-570) that you're waiting and you haven't started the pcm yet. You only starts it when you call `snd_pcm_writei()`.
When you wait for audio data you'll be awake only when the current period has been fully processed -- in your first wait the first period wasn't even written -- so in a comfortable situation you should write the whole buffer, wait for the first interrupt, and then write the just processed period, and on and on.

```
Initially, buffer is empty:
  |            |            |
write():
  |############|############|
wait():
  ..............
When we wake up:
  |            |############|
write():
  |############|############|
```

I found the problem is you're writing audio just before it be played, then sometimes it may arrive delayed in the buffer.

Comment: Good catch on the buffer size, however that's just over-allocating in my case (48000KHz) and it was temporary code. Also I understand snd_pcm_wait() should return immediately if avail >= avail_min so I'm not really waiting until the buffer fills, am I right? Besides original I was only waiting when I get EAGAIN and it was still happening. Now you may be right about your final conclusion by what can I do about it? Filling the buffer first is not the solution because the audio may come from a network stream so it may still happen.

Comment: I did noticed that sometimes just before calling snd_pcm_writei() snd_pcm_delay() returns (buffer_size - avail) + 1024 but the next write still succeeds. So I guess I'm not underruning the ring buffer but the hardware buffer is? If that's the case what should I do? Should I just sleep for a period time when (delay - (buffer_size-avail)) > 0 to let the ringbuffer underrun so I can detect it?

Comment: Also the glitch doesn't sound like just a delay, it sounds like the audio is being played out of order, as if the buffer pointers are getting corrupted somehow. I even confirmed that I'm writing in the right order by also writing to a file.

Comment: @fernan I must agree with you, ALSA documentation is scarce. Yes, snd_pcm_wait() will return immediately when (avail >= avail_min). snd_pcm_writei() returns EAGAIN when (avail == 0). When audio arrives delayed from network you should drop it and send zeroes to the pcm. I don't think ALSA pointers are messy (and probably they aren't). Also, I don't think you should sleep(), but simply make sure there is always audio in ring buffer.

Comment: I will have to do more testing on real hardware since I think QEMU is screwing my tests. It'll take a while since it takes hours to reproduce the glitch on real hardware. Regarding the return value of snd_pcm_writei(), that doesn't seem to be the case, at least in all the hardware I've tested, it either succeeds completely or returns EAGAIN. I'm logging a message whenever there is a partial write and I've never seen it happen.